# Android Facebook SDK 3.0 Integration with application to Post on Wall

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

In Android project trying to have a button to post on wall in facebook by user. When that button is clicked need to check whether user is already logged in using other facebook app if so i need to open Post On Wall Dialog with prefilled data to be shared. Please direct me in this to achieve.

I tried following this tutorial http://www.integratingstuff.com/2010/10/14/integrating-facebook-into-an-android-application/ 
but after asking for user credentials in a webview the page navigates to main activity instead of opening the post on wall dialog. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

Have you tried using the Facebook SDK website? Try looking at the below two links on the Facebook SDK website:

How to log in:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/login-with-facebook/

How to publish to a feed:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/publish-to-feed/

There is also an example application provided with the Facebook SDK 3.0 which can be loaded into eclpise and onto a device for you to better understand how it works (need to add your own APP key of course). There is also the Scrumptious Tutorial on the Facebook SDK site that can run you through everything. 
Found here:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/androidsdk/3.0/scrumptious/

Comment: Thanks i have tried with HelloFacebook sample, for other sample app provided in Facebook SDK is not running. I have used the same APP_ID for all samples. Whether i need to use a seperate APP_ID for each sample?

Comment: Same APP_ID is fine, as long as it is your own that you have got from your registered facebook dev account

Comment: But if i run the session login sample it opens a facebook page states that SessionLoginSample is misconfigured for facebook login.

Comment: That is a common problem when you have not signed the application with the same key used to obtain the APP_ID, make sure you have put your APP_ID into the sample